# Как обнулить массив POST, если форма не отправлена, но страница перезагружена

Tags: php, post

У меня есть такая страница. При загрузке генерируется число картинками и пользователь должен ввести число с картинки. Если правильно ввёл - то идёт на страницу `calculator.php`.
При отправке формы страница перезагружается и проверяется - если рандомное число, сохранённое в сессии равняется тому, что написали в форме, то происходит переход на страницу

Проблема в том, что если обновлять страницу просто так, то если написать неправильно значение, у нас в массив `$_POST` запишется введённое число, а потом обновлять страницу, и оно перейдёт на страницу, когда радномное значение в сессии, попадёт под значение из массива `$_POST`.
Можно ли сделать так, если ты обновляешь страницу и не отправляешь форму, то массив `$_POST` будет пустым
JavaScript нельзя использовать

```html
<?php
    session_start(); 
    $err = 1;
    if ($_SESSION['rand_nb'] ==  $_POST['capcha_nb'] && $_SESSION['rand_nb'] != null) {
        $err = 0;
        $_SESSION['rand_nb'] = null;
        header('Location: calculator.php');
        exit();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
<body>
<div class="numbers">
<?php

    function printImgNmb($nbr) {
        global $arrPic;
        $nbr = strval($nbr);
        $len = strlen($nbr);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $ost = $nbr[$i];
            echo '<img height="150px;" src=' . $arrPic[$ost] . '>';
        }
    }

    function randomNbr($len) {
        $rndmLength = random_int(1, $len);
        $rndm = random_int(0, pow(10, $rndmLength) - 1);
        return $rndm;
    }

    $arrPic = glob("numbers/*.jpg");

    $rndm = randomNbr(1);
    $_SESSION['rand_nb'] = $rndm;
    printImgNmb($rndm);

?>

<form method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            Введите число с картинки
            <input type="text" name="capcha_nb" placeholder="Введите ваш ответ">
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
        if ($err == 1 && !empty($_POST)) {
            echo '<p style="color: red">Вы ввели неправильное число</p>';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_capcha">
    <input type="reset" name="reset_capcha">
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынести скрипт генерации числа и страницы в один скрипт, а проверку и редиректы - в другой.

Примерно так:

captcha.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
<body>
<div class="numbers">
<?php

    function printImgNmb($nbr) {
        global $arrPic;
        $nbr = strval($nbr);
        $len = strlen($nbr);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $ost = $nbr[$i];
            echo '<img height="150px;" src=' . $arrPic[$ost] . '>';
        }
    }

    function randomNbr($len) {
        $rndmLength = random_int(1, $len);
        $rndm = random_int(0, pow(10, $rndmLength) - 1);
        return $rndm;
    }

    $arrPic = glob("numbers/*.jpg");

    $rndm = randomNbr(1);
    $_SESSION['rand_nb'] = $rndm;
    printImgNmb($rndm);

?>

<form method="post" action="redirect.php">
    <p>
        <label>
            Введите число с картинки
            <input type="text" name="capcha_nb" placeholder="Введите ваш ответ">
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
        if ($err == 1 && !empty($_POST)) {
            echo '<p style="color: red">Вы ввели неправильное число</p>';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_capcha">
    <input type="reset" name="reset_capcha">
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

redirect.php

```
    <?php
session_start(); 
        $err = 1;
        if ($_SESSION['rand_nb'] ==  $_POST['capcha_nb'] && $_SESSION['rand_nb'] != null) {
            $err = 0;
            $_SESSION['rand_nb'] = null;
            header('Location: calculator.php');
            exit();
        }else{
    header('Location: captcha.php');
    }
```

Comment: по правде плохо понимаю

Comment: @МихаилКамахин добавил ваш измененный код